# Strange colors when attaching laptop to TV via HDMI on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hdmi, colors

Every time I attach my laptop to a TV at work I get 
[these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY44f.jpg) strange colors. My coworkers don't seem to have this issue. The problem only exists when I attach it to a TV, normal monitors work just fine. Can someone tell me what's going on?

The laptop I use is an XPS 13 9360

Comment: Are you using an adapter HDMI to VGA ?

Comment: I'm using an HDMI to USB-C adapter

Comment: It looks like we are in the same boat... same laptop (XPS 13 Kaby Lake) and same TV monitor brand (Samsung).
This is not exactly a solution but as a workaround after plugging in the TV monitor you can turn TV off and then on: colors should be rendered normally.
Same adapter on Windows (or with Linux but on a different brand TV) works just fine. I didn't find your post before, so mine is a duplicate of this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/850799/usb-c-to-hdmi-on-dell-xps-13-9360 I'm still investigating but not even close to a solution it seems...

Comment: same here: samsung tv and xps 9360. Turning off and on the tv does not resolve the issue

Comment: xps 9360, samsung tv. Sent audio through and changed the volume and now colors are correct...really weird issue

Comment: Confirming that if you send audio through HDMI the issue gets solved, but not immediately. I'm able to fix it by playing audio, opening the config tool, turning on/off the tv. Eventually the colors snap and everything looks ok.

Comment: I can add that I never saw this issue with my Dell XPS 13 on Ubuntu 12.04 (sputnik) when connected to a Samsung Smart TV via DP to HDMI dongle, but since switching to 16.04 it consistently happens when connecting to Samsung Smart TVs (at least two different models). I have not seen it happen with other types of TVs or monitors.

Comment: Forwarded comment by @beanjammin: 
I can add that I never saw this issue with my Dell XPS 13 on Ubuntu 12.04 (sputnik) when connected to a Samsung Smart TV via DP to HDMI dongle, but since switching to 16.04 it consistently happens when connecting to Samsung Smart TVs (at least two different models). I have not seen it happen with other types of TVs or monitors.